# Create a table with wordpress plugin boilerplate

Tags: plugins, database, wpdb, table

I am a new wordpress developer and i would like to create my first wordpress plugin based to wp plugin boilerplate template plugin.
My plugin will have to do with my clients data so for this reason i would like to create a wp custom table in wpdb.
I would like to include something like a class-data-table.php and class-insert-into-table.php. How should be those to classes based to wp boilerplate plugin and where i have to call this two classes. 
Thanks in advance.

P.S. : I dont want to mess with wp taxonomies but create my own table :)

Comment: Are you 100% *sure* you need your own table and can't use post types / post meta / taxonomies? Explain why you think you do.

Comment: @Milo yeap! I need  my own table, cause i have something in my mind, kind to share the data with an another server.